# Show pop up from Datatable in shiny with subset of other dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, subset, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app that displays a number of products depending on the search.
It subsets a large dataset and shows me the products I want that match.

I have another dataframe that has the reviews of said products.
I would like that when a specific row is clicked the review information appears in a different datatable.
The second datatable also needs to be a subset based on the Catalog Number (here is `A`column.

All help appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A= c("BX002","BX006", "BX008"),
                  B= c("Actin","Tubulin", "GAPDH"),
                  C = c("Mouse","Human", "Human"),
                  D = c("WB","WB", "IHC"))
df2 <- data.frame(A= c("BX002","BX006", "BX008"),
                B= c("Actin","Tubulin", "GAPDH"),
                 C = c("5","5", "4"),
                D = c("Good","Good", "Bad"),
                E = c("Kidney", "Liver", "Heart"))

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
        ui = dashboardPage(
                           dashboardHeader(                      
                                   title = "Search"),
                           dashboardSidebar(
                                        sidebarMenu(
                                                menuItem("Search Product", tabName = "product", icon = icon("search")))),
                           dashboardBody(
                           tabItems(
                           tabItem("product",
                                   fluidPage(
                                        sidebarLayout(
                                                sidebarPanel(textInput("name", "Protein name", value = ""),
                                                              submitButton("Search")),
                                                 mainPanel(
                                                        tabsetPanel(
                                                                tabPanel("Products", dataTableOutput("table1")))))))))),



 server =  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

         output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({

                 validate(need(input$name != "", "Please select a Protein Name"))

                 search <- input$name
                 df <- subset(df1, grepl(search, df1$B, ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE)


                 datatable(df, escape = FALSE, selection = "single")

         })
                 observeEvent(input$table1_rows_selected,
                              {
                                      df <- subset(df2, df2$A == input$table1_rows_selected$A)
                                      showModal(modalDialog(
                                              title = "Reviews",
                                              df

                                      ))
                              })   


         })

)
```

I have tried a few methods but cant make it work.

This is my last atempt, no box popup, no error message nothing.

best

Answer (score 1):

I took some liberties with your formatting to make it simpler to recreate.

This should give you the jist of how the `modalDialog`function works with `DT`.

Here's a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput('name','Protein Name'),
  dataTableOutput('table1')


)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  df1 <- data.frame(A= c("BX002","BX006", "BX008"),
                    B= c("Actin","Tubulin", "GAPDH"),
                    C = c("Mouse","Human", "Human"),
                    D = c("WB","WB", "IHC"))
  df2 <- data.frame(A= c("BX002","BX006", "BX008"),
                    B= c("Actin","Tubulin", "GAPDH"),
                    C = c("5","5", "4"),
                    D = c("Good","Good", "Bad"),
                    E = c("Kidney", "Liver", "Heart"))


  tbl1 <- reactive({
    if(nchar(input$name)>0){

      df1[which(tolower(input$name) == tolower(df1$B)),]
    }

  })


  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    if(nchar(input$name)>0){
    datatable(tbl1(),selection = 'single')
    }

  })

  review_tbl <- reactive({

    df2[which(df1[input$table1_rows_selected,1]==df2$A),]

  })


  observeEvent(input$table1_rows_selected,{

    showModal(
      modalDialog(
      renderDataTable({
        review_tbl()
      })

        ))
})



}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it cannot work with the which function. Because it only give exact match, and no search is made with the exact match of the products. A lot of them have greek letters and so on. Unfortunately it did not work for me. I adjusted your code to mine specification code and result is `Warning: Error in datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)` ! I dont know what is wrong, but I need to subset the reviews dataframe so I dont get all the columns.

Comment: You are correct. However, you should be able to adjust that particular code chunk (the reactive `tbl1`) to render a more expansive search return table. The reactive `review_tbl` logic shouldn't change.

Comment: It didnt seem to result with me. There is a lot of HTML and Hyperlinking after so I guess it wont be able to find it. I found another solution. Now I just need to incorporate a sign up panel. Thank you very much.